# Return to Navigation Controller index after modal dismissal (no storyboards)

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

I am attempting to present a view controller modally from within a navigation controller stack and then return to that specific view controller index after dismissal. This `NavigationController` is within a `UITabBarController`.

My app is written with XIBs and programatic navigation controllers and tab bar controllers. I am not using storyboards. Navigation Controller navigation is all done with `self.navigationController.pushViewController(viewController: TabOnePageTwoViewController, animated: true)`

Here is my view controller configuration.

`RootTabBarController` -> `UINavigationController(rootViewController: TabOneController)` -> `TabOnePageOneController` -> `ModalView`

The issue is, when I `self.dismiss()` from within the modal presented view, I am returned to the root of the navigation controller instead of the view which presented the modal, `TabOneController`

I am thinking the right way to do this is select the view controller out of the navigation controller stack and `popToViewController` for the right one.

To accomplish this, I am thinking that in the completion block of `self.dismiss()` I need to navigate to my correct view controller.

```
    let viewControllers = self.navigationController!.viewControllers

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        for aViewController in viewControllers {
            if(aViewController is TabOnePageTwoViewViewController){
                print("navigating back to page one now")
                self.navigationController!.popToViewController(aViewController, animated: true);
            }
        }
    })
```

`

Unfortunately, this does not work. As far as I can tell, `self.navigationController` is not accessible from within the modal view.

How can I return to a navigation controller index after dismissing a modal it presented?

I have uploaded the example app to github at the following URL: https://github.com/thexande/TabControllerAndNavigationControllerExample

If you know programatic navigation within IOS well, download it and take a look!

THANKS ALL!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken a look on your sample project on `Github`.

There is only a minor problem why your sample project does not work properly.

You should be setting up the navigationStack in the `RootTabBarViewController` `viewDidLoad` method, not it `viewWillAppear`. This is some weird behaviour, maybe a bug in the framework, i can not find any documentation why should it happen there, but it does.

So remove `viewWillAppear` and your `viewDidLoad` should look the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        let tabOne = UINavigationController(rootViewController: TabOneViewController())
        tabOne.title = "Tab One"
        let tabTwo = UINavigationController(rootViewController: TabTwoViewController())
        tabTwo.title = "Tab Two"
        self.viewControllers = [tabOne, tabTwo]
}
```